# I need to filter the column from the beginning of a sentence

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

In my code, I can filter a column from exact texts, and it works without problems. However, it is necessary to filter another column with the beginning of a sentence.
The phrases in this column are:
A_2020.092222
A_2020.090787
B_2020.983898
B_2020.209308
So, I need to receive everything that starts with A_20 and B_20.

Thanks in advance

My code:

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import zipfile, urllib.request, shutil, time, csv, datetime, os, sys, os.path


#location
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
file_csv = "/home/Downloads/source.CSV"
file_csv_new = "/var/www/html/Data/Test.csv"

#open CSV
with open(file_csv, 'r', encoding='CP1251') as file:
 reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
 data = list(reader)

#list to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#filter UF
df = df.loc[df[9].isin(['PR','SC','RS'])]

#filter key
# A_ & B_
df = df.loc[df[35].isin(['A_20','B_20'])]

#print (df)
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...]
#Index: []

#[0 rows x 119 columns]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following a try:

```
lst1 = ['A_2020.092222', 'A_2020.090787 ', 'B_2020.983898', 'B_2020.209308', 'C_2020.209308', 'D_2020.209308'] 

df = pd.DataFrame(lst1,   columns =['Name']) 

df.loc[df.Name.str.startswith(('A_20','B_20'))]
```

Comment: An explanation of what this code does and why the OP should try it would be of benefit here!

Comment: Well, it filters the record from the beginging, what the MacDevin was looking for. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html

Comment: It works! Thanks @Priyanka  `df = df.loc[df[40].str.startswith(('Org. Chave','A_20','B_20'))]`